# Adding a second-order join table in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm upgrading a 2-year-old project and need to create more complex model relationships; I'm a little out of my depth.

I had these tables:

- items
- addons
- orders
- items_addons

Now I've added these tables:

- orders_items
- orders_items_addons

I am getting lost in updating my model associations (vis-a-vis brain-to-mush phenomenon), and consequently I can't get Cake to include `orders_items_addons` in `find()` operations from OrdersController, independent of how deep recursion is.

I have these associations:

*HasAndBelongsToMany*

- **Order**: Item
- **Item**: Order, Addon
- **Addon**: Item, OrdersItem

*BelongsToMany*

- **ItemsAddon**: Item, Addon
- **OrdersItem**: Order, Item
- **OrdersItemsAddon**: OrdersItem, Addon

(I can post the foreign key/classname/join-table info if needed but I'm pretty sure I have these right.)

When executing this `$this->Order->find('all')`, however, I'd been expecting the key `$result['n']['OrderItem']` to exist and it does not, nor is `$this->Order->OrderItem` a valid magic-method.

Can anyone help me get a handle on this?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, I think all you are after is `->find('all')->contain(['orders_items_addons'])` to pull out your associations

Comment: Hrmm, when I try that I get the error `Model "Order" is not associated with model "orders_items_addon"`.

Comment: Yeah so u need to check your associations are correct in the model.  Sorry on mobile so don't have the link but check the docs for associations